# zoom h4n problem 

Tags: zoom

my xlr input on my zoom h4n is not working or picking audio anybody know if this problem is common or not and how to fix it and i have tried to change the phantom power to power up my 2 boom shotgun mics but there was no pickup from the mic to the au

Answer (score 2):

I haven't heard of anything myself regarding the XLR/Phantom on the H4n.

You should try and isolate the problem though in case it's not the XLR/Phantom.

- Try your mics with a different recorder/interface.
- Swap out your XLR cables.
- Try a dynamic mic in your H4n to see if it works.

Try as many possible combinations, with only swapping one out at a time, and you should find out what's wrong eventually - and if it does turn out to be the XLR/Phantom, I'd suggest getting in touch with Zoom.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

i second fred suggestion however i had an issue too with the left channel b4 it was making ramdom noise and i got it replaced with out charge, mind u it was new.